# How to Extract in SQL string value between the 2nd set of '-' dashes in a field

Tags: sql, t-sql, substring, charindex

*I am trying to pull values in between 2nd set of '-' for example

- `RNDC007-PS-160958205220402-1-A.pdf` should pull `160958205220402`
- `1883626-FA-2011978300304402-12-A.pdf` should pull `2011978300304402`

Below is my code I have but I am getting values with the `-` on each side of the value.

For example: `-2011978300304402-`

Also when I run for all records against the table I get the error:

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Which I thought the Case statement would address but its not.
Thanks in Advance for the help!

My Code:

```
SELECT [ID]
  ,[T_File]
  ,[OrderNumber]
  ,[CustOrdNumber]
  ,[LineSeqNum]
  ,[SKU]
  ,[WebLineNum]
  ,CASE WHEN [T_File] LIKE '%.pdf%' THEN SUBSTRING([T_File],CHARINDEX('-', [T_File], CHARINDEX('-', [T_File]) + 1) -0,LEN([T_File]) - CHARINDEX('-', [T_File], CHARINDEX('-', [T_File]) + 1) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(Rtrim([T_File])))) ELSE '' END AS PulledString    
FROM [Portal].[dbo].[PA_URL]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using `Charindex` and `NULLIF`

```
SELECT Substring(string, scd + 1, NULLIF(trd, 0) - NULLIF(scd, 0) - 1) AS result
FROM   (SELECT string,
               Charindex('-', string) AS fst
        FROM   (VALUES('RNDC007-PS-160958205220402-1-A.pdf'),
                      ('1883626-FA-2011978300304402-12-A.pdf'),
                      ('1883626-FA') -- bad data
                      )tc(string)) a
       CROSS apply(VALUES (Charindex('-', string, NULLIF(fst, 0) + 1))) b (scd)
       CROSS apply(VALUES (Charindex('-', string, NULLIF(scd, 0) + 1))) c (trd)
```

For the bad records result will be `NULL`

**Result :**

```
result
---------------
160958205220402
2011978300304402
NULL
```

Comment: Huh... very creative,  using a cross apply to get key/chained positions,   +1

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - Thanks John ;)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is with a `CROSS APPLY` with a little XML.  By default, the XML will parse 5 positions, however, as you can see, it it is easy to expand or contract -- essentially could be reduced to Pos2 = ...

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,T_File varchar(250))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'RNDC007-PS-160958205220402-1-A.pdf should pull "160958205220402"'),
(2,'1883626-FA-2011978300304402-12-A.pdf should pull "2011978300304402"')

Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
        Select Pos1 = xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
              ,Pos2 = xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
              ,Pos3 = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
              ,Pos4 = xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
              ,Pos5 = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
         From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select T_File as [*] For XML Path('')),'-','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
       ) B
```

Returns

[image]